# Local variables in a module don't show their actual values

Tags: symbolic, scoping, variable

I need to do the following transformation that

```
pick[a,b] -> ex[c|->{c[a],c[b]}]
```

ex is a function that accepts a function as parameter which returns a list when called.

`ReplaceAll` replaces all pick at once. But I only want to expand my expression one at a time. For example

```
pick[1,2]+pick[3,4] -> ex[Function[c, {c[1], c[2]}]] + pick[3, 4]
```

Then if I apply the transformation the second time, it becomes

```
ex[Function[c, {c[1], c[2]}]] + ex[Function[c, {c[3], c[4]}]]
```

So I've invented the following function

```
ExpandPick[exp_] := Module[{p, x, y, co},
  p = FirstPosition[exp, pick[x_, y_]];
  x = exp[[Sequence @@ p]][[1]];
  y = exp[[Sequence @@ p]][[2]];
  Print[x];
  Print[y];
  ReplacePart[exp, p -> ex[ Function[co,  {co[x], co[y]}]]]
  ]

ExpandPick[pick[a, b] + pick[c, d]]
```

But the output is

```
ex[Function[co$, {co$[x$227772], co$[y$227772]}]] + pick[3, 4]
```

`x$227772], y$227772` are real eyesores. As I'm working on symbolic level, I need Mathematica to show `a` instead of x$227772.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use `With` instead of `Module`?

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, pick, ex, co]

ExpandPick[exp_] := With[{
   p = FirstPosition[exp, _pick]
   }, With[{
    x = First@Extract[exp, p],
    y = Last@Extract[exp, p]
    },
   ReplacePart[exp, p :> ex[Function[co, {co[x], co[y]}]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from "Function" having the attribute "HoldAll". Therefore, what you have to do, is to wrap "Funtion" with "Evaluate":

```
ExpandPick[exp_] := Module[{p, x, y, co},
  p = FirstPosition[exp, pick[x_, y_]];
  x = exp[[Sequence @@ p]][[1]];
  y = exp[[Sequence @@ p]][[2]];
  Print[x];
  Print[y];
  ReplacePart[exp, 
   p :> Evaluate@ex[Function[co, Evaluate@{co[x], co[y]}]]]
  ]

ExpandPick[pick[a, b] + pick[c, d]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
pick[args___] := Map[#, {args}] &
```